# How to set a CSS selector for links ( a Tag ) for a Class

Tags: html, css, selector

I search for all solutions but nothing help me.

my simple problem is to set a style for a link ( a Tag ) with a class:

```
<a class="logo"></a>
```

I don't want a general style for links or for active ones but for a selected Class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different ways to solute this. Since you do not want a global styling for a link this example will not be it:

```
a{
/* STYLE HERE */
}
```

Since you simply want to style a link with a surtain class use this example:

```
a.logo {
    /* STYLE HERE */
}
```

or

```
logo {
    /* STYLE HERE */
}
```

or

```
a[class="logo"] { 
    /* STYLE HERE */
}
```

The last example is a new way of making this happen, some very old browser wont understand this, so you better stick to the first or second example.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `CSS class selector`.

To apply a style to just a single class you should prefix the class name with a dot (`.`) in your CSS selector.

In this particular case you would do it like this:

```
.logo {
    /* Styles here */
}
```

You can also ensure that only link elements are affected by adding the element selector:

```
a.logo {
    /* Styles here */
}
```

PS. The `CSS id selector` is `#` and it works in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<style>
a[class="logo"] { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

<a class="logo">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add style rules by targeting class :

```
a.logo { color: #aeaeae; }
```